# discord.py (rewrite) Rock paper scissors game still lets me do incorrect statements

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a rock paper scissors game and it kind of works. But when I do for say .rps test it still works even know its supposed to only let you do .rps rock or paper or scissors. I've included all my imports if you would like to test it out.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import os
import random
import asyncio
from asyncio import gather


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".")

@client.command()
async def rps(ctx, user_choice):
    rpsGame = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    if user_choice == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':
        await ctx.send(f'Choice: `{user_choice}`\nBot Choice: `{random.choice(rpsGame)}`')
    elif user_choice != 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':
        await ctx.send('**Error** This command only works with rock, paper, or scissors.')

client.run('token')
```

Comment: `if user_choice == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors'` That is not the right way to check multiple values.  See this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/494134

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or` is `True` if either side of it is `True`, and any non-empty string is "truthy." Here's what you meant to do:

```
    if user_choice == 'rock' or user_choice == 'paper' or user_choice == 'scissors':
        await ctx.send(f'Choice: `{user_choice}`\nBot Choice: `{random.choice(rpsGame)}`')
    else:
        await ctx.send('**Error** This command only works with rock, paper, or scissors.')
```

Answer (score 1):

`if user_choice == 'rock' or 'paper' or 'scissors':`, doesn't means that **if user choice is one of them**. It means **if user choice is rock or paper exist or scissors exist**. You need to change these statements:

```py
@client.command()
async def rps(ctx, user_choice):
    rpsGame = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
    if user_choice.lower() in rpsGame:
        await ctx.send(f'Choice: `{user_choice}`\nBot Choice: `{random.choice(rpsGame)}`')
    elif user_choice.lower() not in rpsGame:
        await ctx.send('**Error** This command only works with rock, paper, or scissors.')
```